# I want my character come back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, avatar

I wrote this code to move my character and it works, BUT it only goes forward... I want it to comeback when it hits the edge of the screen(mine is 1280px). please help !

```
let charPosition = parseInt(character.css('left'));
      for (let i = 0; i < 400; i++) {

        setTimeout(function(){
          if(i<100){
          character.css('left',currentX+=20);

          }else if(i>=100){
          character.css('left',currentX+=20);

          character.css({'background-image':'url(https://gameartpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/03/Golden_Knight_featured.png)'});

          if(charPosition >= 1200){
             character.css('left',currentX-=200);
          }
        }

        }, timer()[i]);
      }

   function timer () {
      let number = 0;
      let array = [];
      for (i =0; i< 400; i++) {
      number = number + 400 - 1 * i;
      array.push(number);
      } return array; }
```

Comment: What kind of object is `character`? doesn't `charPosition` should be a vector <x, y> ?

Comment: Didn't you make another question about the same problem a few hours ago

Comment: Yes, I made it walk forward with different way, but this time I want it to move back also.. lol